# How can I use Serde's custom (de)serialization to update a subset of arbitrary input?

Tags: rust, serde

I need to update specific fields of an arbitrary input file without touching any keys or values that my program does not know about.

Here is an example input file:

```
{ 
  "alpha": {
    "a": 1,
    "z": 2
  },
  "beta": "b"
}
```

I'd like to update `alpha.a` by 100:

```
{ 
  "alpha": {
    "a": 101,
    "z": 2
  },
  "beta": "b"
}
```

It is possible to do this with types like [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.21/serde_json/enum.Value.html) and [`toml::value::Value`](https://docs.rs/toml/0.4.6/toml/value/enum.Value.html), but this code is very cumbersome:

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.66
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.21

use serde_json::Value;

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{ 
      "alpha": {
        "a": 1,
        "z": 2
      },
      "beta": "b"
    }"#;

    let mut to_change: Value = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    {
        let obj = to_change.as_object_mut().unwrap();
        let alpha = obj.get_mut("alpha").unwrap();

        let obj = alpha.as_object_mut().unwrap();
        let num = {
            let a = obj.get("a").unwrap();

            let mut num = a.as_i64().unwrap();
            num += 100;
            num
        };
        obj.insert("a".into(), Value::Number(num.into()));
    }
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&to_change).unwrap());
}
```

I'd much rather use the clean derived syntax:

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.66
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.66
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.21

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct WhatICareAbout {
    alpha: Alpha,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Alpha {
    a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{ 
          "alpha": {
            "a": 1,
            "z": 2
          },
          "beta": "b"
        }"#;

    let mut subobject: WhatICareAbout = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    subobject.alpha.a += 1;
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&subobject).unwrap());
}
```

This runs, but it strips out any unknown keys:

```
{
  "alpha": {
    "a": 2
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can use the pretty `Deserialize` and `Serialize` implementations while still preserving keys and values I don't know about?

An ideal answer would:

- Work for most Serde formats — I'm showing JSON here but my real code is TOML.
- Allow adding, updating, and removing fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As of Serde 1.0.34](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/941#issuecomment-375486935), you can use [`#[serde(flatten)]`](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html) to capture all the unrecognized keys and values you don't care about to create a "catch-all" field:

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.66
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.66
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.21

type Other = serde_json::Map<String, serde_json::Value>;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct WhatICareAbout {
    alpha: Alpha,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    other: Other,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Alpha {
    a: i32,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    other: Other,
}
```

For TOML, you can use a parallel definition of `Other`:

```
type Other = std::collections::BTreeMap<String, Value>;
```

> Am I correct in assuming that the order of keys/formatting will be completely discarded by this approach? (At the very least, I expect `alpha` to be serialized first, regardless of the position it originally occupied)

Yes, the order of the output keys will be based on a combination of the field order in the struct definition and the type of map you choose. Above, a `BTreeMap` is used, so the "other" keys will be alphabetized, but all come after the specific fields.

You could opt into an `IndexMap` which would preserve the order of the "other" keys, although they'd still come relative to the specific fields you've added:

```
extern crate indexmap; // 0.4.1 + features = ["serde-1"]

type Other = indexmap::IndexMap<String, serde_json::Value>;
```

See also:

- [How to (de)serialize a strongly typed JSON dictionary in Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49717966/155423)
- [Is it possible to flatten sub-object fields while parsing with serde_json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41042767/155423)
- [How to deserialize a subfield of a struct from the original struct's JSON with Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44302604/155423)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the order of keys/formatting will be completely discarded by this approach? (At the very least, I expect `alpha` to be serialized first, regardless of the position it originally occupied) If so, a note might be welcome, as using such a "script" on a committed file could result in large changes.

Comment: @MatthieuM. an interesting point! It would normally be relevant to my case of editing a Cargo.toml, which is usually a file committed to source control that is human-edited. In my case, it doesn't matter since it's for the playground.

Comment: When I try this, I get ``error: unknown serde variant attribute `flatten``, even though I have Serde v1.0.70. It would be nice if you could add the necessary ``use`` statements to your answer.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig The crate statements and versions are in the question, but I can copy them if that's not obvious.

Comment: @Shepmaster My bad, I thought that this feature could be used during serialization as well (e.g. to flatten JSON structures). In the end I've just simplified my data structure.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig yes, [that's exactly what I'm doing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2591d19e15336960c4ffedada9558728&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).